# How to remove a country from intl-tel-input

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, prefix, intl-tel-input, mobile-country-code

(new in javascript)

I am asked to remove a country (China) from the dropdown menu of the plugin intl-tel-input

the code below displays the dropdown menu and it looks that it calls the utils.js file to retain the countries

```
var iti = window.intlTelInput(input,
            {
                utilsScript: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/intl-tel-input/utils.js")',
                separateDialCode: false,
                hiddenInput: "mobileNumber",
                preferredCountries: ["lu", "gb","fr","in","us","de"],
            });
```

I found the Chinese prefix and I removed from the utils.js file which it looks like the below:

A part of the code (because the code is huge)

```
var K={1:"US AG AI AS BB BM BS CA DM DO GD GU JM KN KY LC MP MS PR SX TC TT VC VG VI".split(" "),7:["RU","KZ"],20:["EG"],27:["ZA"],30:["GR"],31:["NL"],32:["BE"],33:["FR"],34:["ES"],36:["HU"],39:["IT","VA"],40:["RO"],41:["CH"],43:["AT"],44:["GB","GG","IM","JE"],45:["DK"],46:["SE"],47:["NO","SJ"],48:["PL"],49:["DE"],51:["PE"],52:["MX"],53:["CU"],54:["AR"],55:["BR"],56:["CL"],57:["CO"],58:["VE"],60:["MY"],61:["AU","CC","CX"],62:["ID"],63:["PH"],64:["NZ"],65:["SG"],66:["TH"],81:["JP"],82:["KR"],84:["VN"],90:["TR"],91:["IN"],92:["PK"],93:["AF"],94:["LK"],95:["MM"],98:["IR"],211:["SS"],212:["MA","EH"],213:["DZ"],216:["TN"],218:["LY"],220:["GM"],221:["SN"],222:["MR"],223:["ML"],224:["GN"],225:["CI"],226:["BF"],227:["NE"],228:["TG"],229:["BJ"],230:["MU"],231:["LR"],232:["SL"],233:["GH"],234:["NG"],235:["TD"],236:["CF"],237:["CM"],238:["CV"],239:["ST"],240:["GQ"],241:["GA"],242:["CG"],243:["CD"],244:["AO"],245:["GW"],246:["IO"],247:["AC"],248:["SC"],249:["SD"],250:["RW"],251:["ET"],252:["SO"],
253:["DJ"],254:["KE"],255:["TZ"],256:["UG"],257:["BI"],258:["MZ"],260:["ZM"],261:["MG"],262:["RE","YT"],263:["ZW"],264:["NA"],265:["MW"],266:["LS"],267:["BW"],268:["SZ"],269:["KM"],290:["SH","TA"],291:["ER"],297:["AW"],298:["FO"],299:["GL"],350:["GI"],351:["PT"],352:["LU"],353:["IE"],354:["IS"],355:["AL"],356:["MT"],357:["CY"],358:["FI","AX"],359:["BG"],370:["LT"],371:["LV"],372:["EE"],373:["MD"],374:["AM"],375:["BY"],376:["AD"],377:["MC"],378:["SM"],380:["UA"],381:["RS"],382:["ME"],383:["XK"],385:["HR"],
386:["SI"],387:["BA"],389:["MK"],420:["CZ"],421:["SK"],423:["LI"],500:["FK"],501:["BZ"],502:["GT"],503:["SV"],504:["HN"],505:["NI"],506:["CR"],507:["PA"],508:["PM"],509:["HT"],590:["GP","BL","MF"],591:["BO"],592:["GY"],593:["EC"],594:["GF"],595:["PY"],596:["MQ"],597:["SR"],598:["UY"],599:["CW","BQ"],670:["TL"],672:["NF"],673:["BN"],674:["NR"],675:["PG"],676:["TO"],677:["SB"],678:["VU"],679:["FJ"],680:["PW"],681:["WF"],682:["CK"],683:["NU"],685:["WS"],686:["KI"],687:["NC"],688:["TV"],689:["PF"],690:["TK"],
```

but it doesnt work. The Chinese prefix is still there.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the `intl-tel-input` documentation regarding [Initialisation Options](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#initialisation-options). There is an option called `excludeCountries`.

We can modify your initialisation code to include this option to exclude China:

```
var iti = window.intlTelInput(input,
    {
        utilsScript: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/intl-tel-input/utils.js")',
        separateDialCode: false,
        hiddenInput: "mobileNumber",
        preferredCountries: ["lu", "gb", "fr", "in", "us", "de"],
        excludeCountries: ["cn"]
    });
```

Comment: This seems to work. Lesson learnt: Always to check the documentation. Many thanks @Riddel for the swift answer.

Comment: @ChrisTsag Indeed, it's always the best place to start. On the flipside, a person can debug for 6 hours to save themselves reading 5 minutes of documentation! If the response answered your question then you should mark the answer.